# Image getting corrupted with tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, python-imaging-library

I have an np array (a segmentation mask predicted by a model).
I have to save this mask (array) as an image for visualizing the result.

I am able to save the array as an image using, `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img`.
But when I inspected the saved image, it is found that the image has many corrupted values.

Sample code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# mask is prediction output from a model, of shape HxWx1, pixels can take integer values between 0 and 10.

mask = np.array([
    [[0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[4], [4], [4], [4]],
    [[5], [5], [5], [5]],
    [[6], [6], [6], [6]]
])
print(np.unique(mask))  # unique values present are 0,4,5,6

# Save the predicted mask array as an image
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img('mask.jpg', mask,  scale=False)

# Load the saved image into an array and verify values again
mask_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('mask.jpg', color_mode='grayscale')
loaded_mask = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(mask_img)

print(loaded_mask)
    # [[[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.]],
    #  [[3.], [3.], [3.], [3.]],
    #  [[6.], [6.], [6.], [6.]],
    #  [[6.], [6.], [6.], [6.]]]
print(np.unique(loaded_mask)) # unique values are 1., 3., 6.
```

The retrieved array is not exactly the same as the original array which was my expectation.
In my case, values outside 0 and 10 are meaningless (values correspond to a class) and I have observed values like 11,12, up to 13 in some predictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image fine in `.png` format. The issue that causes in your above example comes from the `.jpg` format which uses a **lossy compression algorithm** and thus the image may lose some of its data but in `.png`, it uses a **lossless compression algorithm**.

```
mask = np.array([
    [[0], [0], [0], [0]],
    [[4], [4], [4], [4]],
    [[5], [5], [5], [5]],
    [[6], [6], [6], [6]]
])
print(np.unique(mask))  # unique values present are 0,4,5,6

# Save the predicted mask array as an image
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img('mask.png', mask,  scale=False)

# Load the saved image into an array and verify values again
mask_img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img('mask.png', color_mode='grayscale')
loaded_mask = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(mask_img)

print(loaded_mask)
    # [[[1.], [1.], [1.], [1.]],
    #  [[3.], [3.], [3.], [3.]],
    #  [[6.], [6.], [6.], [6.]],
    #  [[6.], [6.], [6.], [6.]]]
print(np.unique(loaded_mask)) # unique values are 1., 3., 6.
```

```
[0 4 5 6]
[[[0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]]

 [[4.]
  [4.]
  [4.]
  [4.]]

 [[5.]
  [5.]
  [5.]
  [5.]]

 [[6.]
  [6.]
  [6.]
  [6.]]]
[0. 4. 5. 6.]
```